# Switch between Scenes in Sprite-Kit (Swift) using LabelNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I use `SKLabelNodes` as Buttons and a `if` inside a menu helper to detect touches on them. Printing works (so does detection), but how do I switch to my Game Scene properly?

```
func menuHelper(touches: NSSet) {
        for touch in touches {
            let nodeAtTouch = self.nodeAtPoint(touch.locationInNode(self))
            if nodeAtTouch.name == "title" {
                print("Title pressed")
            }
            else if nodeAtTouch.name == "newGame" {
            let scene = GameScene()
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to make a new scene (and transition, but that's optional) and present it by using appropriate SKView's method:

```
else if nodeAtTouch.name == "newGame" {

   let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1.0)

   let nextScene = GameScene(size: scene!.size)
   nextScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill //set the scale mode like you did in your view controller

   scene?.view?.presentScene(nextScene, transition: transition)
}
```

Without transition , you would just use [presentScene](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKView/presentScene:) method instead of [presentScene:transition](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKView/presentScene:transition:)

Comment: It works, thank you. But I'm still not quite sure what the difference is between yours and mine. Was it basically the last line of yours?

Comment: @FelixF Yup that is the important part. Also I've initialized new scene's size with old scene's size and set the scale mode. So, as I said, the important part is that you have to present the new scene actually to replace the current one. Just creating the new scene will not do that automatically. Hope this make sense!

Comment: Thanks, makes totally sense now! :)